# Why am I able to operate Cupy's NDArray on cuda by using NumPy module?

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, gpu, cupy

I was thinking that numpy is used to operate data on cpu, but I found that when I created a cupy.array, I can still use numpy module to operate it, and it's still on cuda.

Like this

```
x = cp.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
y = cp.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
z = np.add(x,y)
```

It still works!

I thought that maybe numpy has moved data to cpu

So I wrote this

```
print(type(z))
print(z.device)
```

It shows that

```
<class 'cupy.ndarray'>
<CUDA Device 0>
```

It's still on cuda. How did numpy make this? I mean, numpy should work on cpu right? So is it cupy working or numpy working?

Comment: https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/user_guide/interoperability.html